# Can we add more form field in braintree payments hosted fields form?

Tags: braintree

I am taking a look of using hosted fields / form in Braintree (here: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/hosted-fields/setup-and-integration/javascript/v2).

In the example html form on the above page, all the fields it has are all hosted fields (cc number, exp date, cvv).

My question is: in the same form, I want to add a few more normal form fields, to collect other information, such as shipping address, delivery notes, etc.

I tried and looks like it works at least in sandbox, but since the doc doesn't mention anything like that, I just want to confirm it.

Anyone has some idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

You can add any additional fields to the form by just adding more input tags. Using the example from the [docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/hosted-fields/setup-and-integration/javascript/v2#basic-integration), if I wanted to add `first-name` and `last-name` to the form:

```
<form action="/" id="my-sample-form">
  <label for="card-number">Card Number</label>
  <div id="card-number"></div>

  <label for="cvv">CVV</label>
  <div id="cvv"></div>

  <label for="expiration-date">Expiration Date</label>
  <div id="expiration-date"></div>

  <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="first-name" id="first-name">

  <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="last-name" id="last-name">

  <input type="submit" value="Pay" />
</form>
```